# Spring integration - Processing 2 same messages in aggregation differently

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am connecting to TCP socket using spring integration. I send 2 different messages on an outbound gateway which returns same outputs i.e. header as well as payload.

Now I want to process reply messages differently and then aggregate into a single message which can then be processed by main service class.

I tried various techniques but nothing worked.

Is it feasible to do so? If yes, kindly help me out.

Answer (score 2):

You need something to correlate the messages, maybe a header (e.g. the standard correlation id).

Use a header-enricher to set the correlation id header on each outbound message. Send the reply messages to an `<aggregator />` with a simple release strategy (`release-strategy-expression="size() == 2"`). When the second reply is received, a message with a payload (collection of the 2 payloads) will be released.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary. I used header enricher to define header id and evaluating header id in correlation expression strategy. It helped. :)